# amplify push creates extra files for the lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am using amplify cli version 4.45.0 on Mac.

I added a new function using "amplify add function" and followed prompts for Serverless function, python, no edits to the advanced settings and no edits to the local lambda function

ran "pipenv run amplify push"

the push was successful. However, the function in AWS Console shows the following structure. Is this expected?

[image]